# Using ElevateZoom but zoom comes always behind the img

Tags: jquery, zooming

I use elevate zoom plugin and i have an issue with the zoom. I have one container div which holds all the content and a mainDiv which holds the background image of the page  then i try to put a div toZoom but the zoom lens shows always behind the img(behind div toZoom) and in-front of MainDiv..Have anyone had something simular and how to solve it?

```
 <div id="container" style="width:100%;height:100%;position: relative;">
   <div id="MainDiv" style="overflow:hidden;position:absolute; background:url(../Background2.jpg); width:100%;height:100%;background-size:100%;background-repeat:no-repeat;">
<div style=" padding-top:20px; padding-left:20px;border-radius: 10px;width:450px;height:605px;background-color:#FFFFFF;opacity:1;z-index:2; left:calc(0.7% + 451px);top:10px; position: absolute;"> 
    <img id="toZoom"   data-zoom-image="icon1.jpg" width="440px" height="600px" margin="10px" src="icon1.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/Regaddi/elevatezoom/commit/93028ada9814c35cd3ac0bfb037e5904c0d7a4c6

Just make this line in the elevateZoom.js file

```
 self.zoomWindowContainer =$('<div/>').addClass('zoomWindowContainer').css("width",self.options.zoomWindowWidth);
```

with this :

```
    self.zoomWindowContainer = $('<div/>').addClass('zoomWindowContainer').css({
       "width": self.options.zoomWindowWidth,
       "z-index": 999
     });
```